# CalledFromWrongThreadException in SharedPreferenceListener

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an IntentService which updates a preference like this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userPrefs.edit();
editor.putInt("COUNT", intCount);
editor.commit();
```

In my main activity I am listening for preference changes and update a TextView

```
userPrefsListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

  if(key.equals("COUNT")) {

    final TextView txvCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TXV_COUNTER);

    if(txvCounter != null) {

    SharedPreferences userPrefs = getSharedPreferences("USER_SCORE", 0);
    int intCount = userPrefs.getInt("COUNT", 0);
    txvFishcounter.setText(String.format("%03d",intCount));
    }
  }
}
};

userPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(userPrefsListener);
```

For Android 2.3 everything works fine, but for 2.2 I'm getting CalledFromWrongThreadException everytime the OnSharedListener is triggered.

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: `This callback will be run on your main thread.`, so can try print your thread name `Thread.currentThread().getName()`, if is not main thread, may be it's the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the `CalledFromWrongThreadException` is raised, is because the `OnChangeListener` is not supposed to be called from the `IntentService`.

What you could do though, is sending a Broadcast (where you can actually include the value as well).

In case you are only using the `SharedPreference` for communication, you can replace it entirely (and I would recommend this, as SharedPreferences are wasting Write Cycles).

You could use a code like this for sending a Broadcast:

```
/**
 * Send an Intent with the Broadcast, a permission and a Bundle
 * 
 * @param context
 *            A context to use
 * @param broadcast
 *            String to use, eg. "de.bulling.smstalk.ENABLE"
 * @param permission
 *            Permission needed for receiving
 * @param bundle
 *            Extras to attach
 */
public static void send_broadcast(Context context, String broadcast, String permission, Bundle bundle) {
    //SettingsClass.log_me(tag, "Sending broadcast " + broadcast);
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(broadcast);
    if (bundle != null) {
        i.putExtras(bundle);
    }
    if (permission != null) {
        context.sendBroadcast(i, permission);
    } else {
        context.sendBroadcast(i);
    }
}
```

You should include a custom permission as well, so other apps don't get the Broadcast, but it is not necessarily needed.

To receive the Broadcast, register a Receiver in your Activity, eg

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        doSomething();
    }
};



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(YOURBROADCAST);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    [...]
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Also you should consider using `Handler`s, so your methods in the OnChangeListener call are run by the MainUI thread.

Example:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
Runnable myCode = new Runnable(){
     @Override
     protected void onRun() {
          yourCode();
          }
     };
mHandler.run(myCode);
```

This has also the advantage of running the code delayed with `runDelayed()`, so you don't have to use `sleep`, and you UI will be still responding.

Answer (score 3):

The thread running the `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` callback is not the main UI thread in the 2.2 device which give you `CalledFromWrongThreadException` (therefore violating the second of the [Android UI thread access rules](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Threads) of only calling UI toolkit from the UI thread). A straightforward way to get code to run on the UI thread is to use [Activity.runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29). This could be done simply by wrapping the body of your code in a new `Runnable`:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Code which updates UI controls goes here.
    }
});
```

A short discussion of the change between 2.2 and 2.3 and code snippets of why it occurred can be found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4235f126e33222af).